# IE shows an extra layer

Tags: jquery, css, position

If it's loaded in IE, I see an extra layer with red background. But if it's loaded in Firefox, it's not there. Anyone know how I can get rid of the layer so I only see the image and the "X" icon?

I tried changing size and also made it visible and hidden, nothing is working.

Edit: now that i added a red background color, it shows up in Firefox as well.

I just want to see the image and the "X" icon.

Comment: remove the `background-color` declaration from `.window`?

Comment: Your class "window" has `background-color: red`. If I remove that, it doesn't show up in either browser. Make sure your CSS file isn't cached by IE.

Comment: Probably caching.  In IE, right click at top of screen, add Command Menu.  Right-click the Command Menu area and choose Customize>Add or Remove Commands.  Put the "Delete browsing history" button where you can get at it.  :)  That help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is dropping down because of `a.close`, too stop that, set `a.close` to `position: absolute` instead of `position:relative` but even then, your image is not big enough to cover the red area.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the rule in `.window` class for `background-color: #ff0000;`

Comment: i just removed the background color for interim. Thanks